# Can save Jars in SonarQube with Plugin developement?

Tags: plugins, sonarqube

I am working on a plugin where I need to generate a few artifacts with mix of jars and note files. Can I save these artifacts inside SonarQube and make it downloadable in SonarQube?

Comment: Could you be more explicit about your use case ?

Comment: I am scanning the code by writing custom plugin. As part of that, I am generating few custom files in form of Jar. This should be downloadable by sonarqube users. I created a page using javascript in sonarqube for my plugin. I wanted to make the generated jars either zip format or any other format downloadable. In that aspect, I am trying to find options to save these generated jars in any form in SonarQube server. Hope this clarifies. Please let me know if more details are required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you explain me what will the user will do with this jar ? Because it won't be possible to store them into SonarQube, but instead you could replace your jar by some measures.

Comment: Thanks for your message. This jar will be used by end users as a library in the application. I want to generate fixes using this plugin. The output has to be in jar but we can deliver it in zip format on top of jar file. Is this feasible? Can we store this in SonarQube/Data folders? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but if my understanding is correct, what you want to do should not be part of SonarQube, but of another tool. The goal of SonarQube is to help people improve the quality of projects using the web interface or using SonarLint from IDE. Your use case seems like a "hack" to me.

Comment: Thanks for your note. I want to analyze the code and then generate a solution after analysis as well. This solution helps protecting the application where SQ raised issues. Please suggest.

Comment: You should then have a look a what is done by SonarLint : http://www.sonarlint.org/

Comment: Thank you Julien. In my case, I dont want to fix or suggest code as tools like SonarLint provides this option. But I want to generate solution where a code is not fixed with all these suggestions. Please suggest.

Comment: Then I'm sorry but I've no idea

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed though process for the entire discussion. I will update you as I find alternatives. Appreciate your valuable time.